# ¿Cómo evitar un desbordamiento de búfer cuando se pide una cadena con scanf?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char cadena[5] = {0};
    int c = 10;
    printf("Escriba una cadena: ");
    scanf("%s", cadena);
    
    printf("Resultado: %s, %d", cadena, c);
    return 0;
}
```

El problema radica que cuando el usuario ingrese `5` o más caracteres, el *array* se desborda (se paso de los límites) y de paso, sobrescribe el contenido de la variable `c`.

**Ejemplo:**

Sí el usuario ingresa por teclado un `12345`, el resultado en pantalla sería:

```c
Resultado: 12345, 0
```

En el ejemplo se refleja como la variable `c` pierde el valor que tenía anteriormente.
Entonces, la pregunta es: ¿Cómo evito este posible desbordamiento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > ¿Cómo evitar un desbordamiento de búfer cuando se pide una cadena con scanf?

Para evitar el desbordamiento, necesitamos indicarle a la función `scanf` hasta que caracteres debe leer.

Y esto se lo hace de la siguiente manera:

```c
scanf("%4s", cadena);
```

Aquí le indicamos a la función `scanf` que solo podrá leer hasta `4` caracteres. Sí el usuario llegara a escribir `5` o más caracteres, se quedan en el búfer del teclado.

**Nota:** La última posición del *array* es para el caracter nulo.

### **Preguntas frecuentes:**

##### ¿Por qué no puedo agregar en el especificador de formato un `5`?

Miremos el siguiente código:

```c
scanf("%5s", cadena);
```

Aquí le indico a `scanf` que podrá leer hasta `5` caracteres. El problema radica que no estamos dejando un espacio para el caracter nulo, por lo tanto, sucederá otro [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer).

Imagínate que el *array* y la variable `c` están en la memoria de esta forma:

```c
Address: 0x0A  0x0B  0x0C  0x0D  0x0E  0x0F  
Data:     0     0     0     0     0     10
array-----^-----^-----^-----^-----^     ^---- c
```

Ahora, cuando el usuario ingrese un `Holas`, entonces la función `scanf` irá escribiendo en el *array* de esta forma:

```c
Address: 0x0A  0x0B  0x0C  0x0D  0x0E  0x0F  
Data:     H     o     l     a     s     10
array-----^-----^-----^-----^-----^     ^---- c
```

Pero la función `scanf` es la encargada de asignar el caracter nulo al *array*, por ende, lo hará en la dirección `0x0F`, que justamente es de la variable `c`:

```c
Address: 0x0A  0x0B  0x0C  0x0D  0x0E  0x0F  
Data:     H     o     l     a     s     \0
array-----^-----^-----^-----^-----^     ^---- c
```

¡Volvimos a sobrescribir el contenido de la variable `c`! Aquí nos queda claro que debemos lograr que `scanf` solo pueda leer hasta `4` caracteres para que no suceda ningún desbordamiento.

**Nota:** En el ejemplo anterior, la dirección `0x0E` es la que debe ser para el caracter nulo.

##### ¿Qué pasa si necesito leer una cadena con espacios?

Nunca uses la función [gets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) para leer cadenas con espacios, porque está obsoleta y no forma parte del estándar [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)), esto significa que se pierde portabilidad, ya que no todos los compiladores tendrán soporte para esta función.

El problema de esta función es que no permite especificar el tamaño del *array*, así que es propenso a que ocurra un desbordamiento de búfer.

Así que una manera segura de leer cadenas con espacios, es con la función [fgets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

```c
fgets(cadena, sizeof cadena, stdin);
```

También existe una alternativa para poder leer cadenas con espacios usando `scanf`:

```c
scanf("%5[^\n]", cadena);
```

`[^\n]` significa que `scanf` leerá cualquier caracter (incluso un espacio) **excepto** el salto de línea.

### Un ejemplo sobre este tipo de ataque...

Los **usuarios malintencionados** podrían aprovechar esta *vulnerabilidad* para lograr cambiar el **comportamiento deseado del programa**, así que debes evitar que este *error* esté integrado en la aplicación.

He sacado un **ejemplo** de esta [página](https://www.veracode.com/security/buffer-overflow) donde se puede reflejar una consecuencia de desbordamiento de búfer.

> Considere un programa que solicita una contraseña de usuario para otorgarle acceso al sistema. En el siguiente código, la contraseña correcta otorga al usuario privilegios de root. Si la contraseña es incorrecta, el programa no otorgará privilegios al usuario.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define EXAMPLE_PASSWORD "1234"

int main(void)
{
    char password[16];
    int pass = 0;
    printf("Enter the password:\n");
    scanf("%s", password);
    if(!strcmp(password, EXAMPLE_PASSWORD))
    {
        printf("Correct Password!\n");
        pass = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Wrong Password!\n");
    }
    
    if(pass)
    {
        printf("Root privileges given to the user!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Este programa es vulnerable a un ataque de desbordamiento de búfer, puesto si el usuario ingresa más de 16 caracteres, desborda el *array* `password` (se pasa de su límite).

Tomemos como ejemplo las siguientes entradas:

```sh
$ ./test
Enter the password:
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
Wrong Password!
Root privileges given to the user!
```

Aquí el usuario obtiene los privilegios de root aunque la contraseña esté incorrecta y este comportamiento es causado por sobrescribir la variable `pass`, por lo que la condición `if(pass)` se cumpliría, ya que `pass` sería diferente a cero.

Así que esta es una forma como alguien podría tener acceso al todo sistema y robar información confidencial de una empresa (por poner un ejemplo).

También se debe tomar en cuenta que el desbordamiento de búfer ocasiona un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido), esto significa que el programa puede funcionar o puede que no funcione (al tener [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) el comportamiento del programa es arbitrario, puede ocurrir cualquier cosa).

En el ejemplo anterior se presentó un posible comportamiento del programa: *Otorgarle al usuario privilegios de root aunque la contraseña sea incorrecta* y la causa fue por sobrescribir la memoria del programa, sin embargo, pudo haber ocurrido otro comportamiento, como por ejemplo, intentar acceder a una dirección de memoria que no fue asignada al proceso actual (el programa ejecutándose), esto provocaría que el sistema operativo mate al proceso actual, por lo que el programa dejaría de funcionar.

Y por último, para eliminar ese *posible desbordamiento* del ejemplo anterior, simplemente debemos especificar el tamaño del *array* en la función `scanf`:

```c
int main(void)
{
    char password[16];
    int pass = 0;
    printf("Enter the password:\n");
    scanf("%15s", password);
```

¡Con esto aseguramos que solo se ingrese 15 caracteres! ¡Dile adios a esta vulnerabilidad!