# ¿Por qué el resultado de la condición es falso cuando comparo caracteres?

Tags: c

Estaba programando y he tenido una duda al hacer un condicional , ¿alguien me puede decir porque no me reconoce los valores que he puesto en el `if(A==...)`?

```
printf("Fichero con cosas, quiere escrbir algo mas o hacer uno nuevo:");
scanf("%s",A);
if(A =='a')
{
    f2=fopen(archivo2,"a");
}
if(A=='w')
{
    f2=fopen(archivo2,"w");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > ¿Por qué el resultado de la condición es falso cuando comparo caracteres?

Miremos el siguiente código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char A[2];
    printf("Fichero con cosas, quiere escrbir algo mas o hacer uno nuevo:");
    scanf("%s", A);
    if(A=='a')
    {
        f2=fopen(archivo2,"a");
    }
    if(A=='w')
    {
        f2=fopen(archivo2,"w");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

En este ejemplo, declaro un *array* de 2 elementos y le pedimos al usuario una cadena, aunque en realidad el usuario solo debería de ingresar únicamente un caracter.

Entonces, sí el usuario teclea la letra `a`, este caracter estará guardado en la posición `0` (aunque en realidad lo que se guarda es el código ASCII del caracter) del *array*.

*scanf* se encargará que el caracter nulo (indica el fin de la cadena) esté en la posición `1`.

Hasta ahí, no hay problemas, pero cuando nos topamos en esta condición:

```c
if(A=='a')
```

Nos damos cuenta que esa condición nunca se cumplirá, porque el identificador `A`, representa la **dirección de memoria del primer elemento del array**. Por lo tanto, estás comparando una dirección con un código ASCII (el de caracter `'a'`). Esa es la razón del porque **SIEMPRE** da `false` la restricción.

Entonces lo que podrías hacer, es usar la función [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) de la cabecera `string.h`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char A[2];
    printf("Fichero con cosas, quiere escrbir algo mas o hacer uno nuevo:");
    scanf("%s", A);
    if(strcmp(A, "a") == 0)
    {
        f2=fopen(archivo2,"a");
    }
    if(strcmp(A, "w") == 0)
    {
        f2=fopen(archivo2,"w");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

De este modo, podrás comparar si dos cadenas son iguales. De igual manera, hay que evitar el [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) en esta línea:

```c
scanf("%s", A);
```

En el *array* `A` solo podemos guardar un caracter + el caracter nulo, así que si el usuario ingresa más de la cuenta, provocará un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido), esto significa que el programa puede funcionar como no puede funcionar, el resultado es arbitrario.

Un posible resultado sería sobrescribir la memoria del propio programa. Otro resultado sería intentar leer o escribir en una dirección que ya es usado por otro proceso, ahí en ese caso, lo normal es que el sistema mate el proceso actual.

En fin, debes evitar el desbordamiento de esta manera:

```c
//Sí el usuario ingresa más de 1 caracter, scanf solo leerá uno.
scanf("%1s", A);
```

En este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383852/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-un-desbordamiento-de-b%C3%BAfer-cuando-se-pide-una-cadena-con-scanf/383853#383853) explico con más detalle como evitar el desbordamiento cuando pides una cadena con `scanf`.

**Solución 2:** En vez de pedir una cadena, podrías pedir únicamente un caracter:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //En esta variable guardamos el caracter.
    char A;
    printf("Fichero con cosas, quiere escrbir algo mas o hacer uno nuevo:");
    //Hay que pasar la dirección de memoria de A
    scanf("%c", &A);
    //Ahora si podemos comparar códigos ASCII :)
    if(A == 'a')
    {
        f2=fopen(archivo2,"a");
    }
    //Ahora si podemos comparar códigos ASCII :)
    if(A == 'w')
    {
        f2=fopen(archivo2,"w");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

De este modo, nos evitamos tres cosas:

**1.-** No hay que preocuparse por el desbordamiento de búfer.

**2.-** No necesitamos usar la función `strcmp`.

**3.-** No hay que enfocarse en dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%s", A);
```

no lee un caracter, lee *una cadena*.

Además, para que *scanf* te meta el valor que lee en *A*, debes pasarle **la dirección de A**.

```
scanf("%c", &A);
```

Si haces

```
char cadena[5];
scanf("%s", cadena);
```

esto funciona porque *cadena* sin subíndices ya es la dirección del array (más concretamente la del primer elemento).

Comment: Si , lo tenia igual que me dices tu , lo siento igual no me explique bien , lo que me pasa es que al poner if(A==(valor de scanf)) no se como poner "valor de scanf" para que cuando lo ponga lo identifique

Comment: @Wow realmente no te explicas ¿No es *A* es "valor de scanf"?

Comment: A ver lo siento enserio , lo que necesito no es como poner scanf y tal porque eso me lo lee bien , lo que no me identifica es el condicional , me explico , yo quiero poner en el programa una "a" o "w" y que me haga una de las dos cosas segun lo que ponga en cada parte , pero no se como ponerlo para que me lo recoja en el if, yo he puesto A=='w' , pero no funciona

Comment: Debería funcionar. Haz un *printf* del valor de A para ver qué se guarda.

Comment: Si eso es lo que hice pero al hacer el printf , me sale el valor que habia puesto en el scanf asi que supongo que no es ese el problema

Comment: No tiene sentido. ¿Puedes poner el ejemplo **completo** tal como dices que lo tienes, en vez de decir "lo tenía así" o "lo tenía asá"? Dale al botón de "editar."