# Comparison between pointer and integer al compilar

Tags: c

Se supone me debe dar que alumno pasa y cual no pasa la materia, ¿Qué
debo cambiar para que el código funcione?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct alumnos {
 int alum[50];
    float cal[10];
    }alumno[10];
    int i;
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Ingresa el nombre de 10 alumnos junto con su calificacion de la materia de matematicas\n");
    
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("Nombre del alumno: \n");
        scanf("%s", alumno[i].alum);
        printf("Ingrese calificacion: \n");
        scanf("%f", alumno[i].cal);
        if(alumno[i].cal>=6){
            printf("Pasa\n");
        }if(alumno[i].cal<6){
            printf("No pasa\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. No pongas el código como captura de pantalla, ponlo como texto por favor.

Comment: `cal`, por tu definición, es un arreglo de `floats`. Tendrías que especificar cuál de los items en `cal` querrías usar para comparar (lo cual me lleva a pensar que no tienes bien tu estructura de datos.... parece que cada alumno va a tener 10 calificaciones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float cal[10];
```

y

```
if(alumno[i].cal>=6){
```

*cal* es un array de 10 floats. C (y C++) trata los arrays como punteros, la única diferencia es que les asigna automáticamente el espacio requerido (y no tienes que hacer *malloc*).

En tus *if*s, estás comparando **un array de números** con un único número. No tiene sentido. Si hicieras

```
if (alumno[i].cal[0] >= 6) {
```

ya estarías comparando un número (el primer número del array) con un número, que es algo que tiene sentido.

Como la comparación le parece rara, te muestra un *warning*. **El programa es compilado** (C/C++ permiten muchas cosas raras), pero al menos te avisa de que igual quieres revisar lo que pasa.

Comment: ¡Funcionó! ¡Gracias!

Comment: @Zamx por favor, marca la respuesta como aceptada si resolvió tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El código tiene varias fallas:

**1.-** `alum` es un *array* de enteros y después intentas pedir una cadena como si `alum` fuera un *array* de caracteres:

```c
scanf("%s", alumno[i].alum);
```

**Solución:** `alum` debe ser un *array* de caracteres:

```c
struct alumnos 
{
    char alum[50];
    float cal[10];
}alumno[10];
```

**2.-** No tiene sentido comparar una dirección de memoria con un entero:

```c
if(alumno[i].cal>=6)
```

Ten en cuenta que `cal` es una simple alias de la dirección del primer elemento del *array*, así que el resultado que esperaras puede ser erróneo.

Noto que tu intención es pedir `10` calificaciones por teclado y verificar si es mayor o igual a `6`, para lograr esto, debes hacer uso de un bucle anidado:

```c
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    printf("Ingrese la %d calificacion: \n", j + 1);
    scanf("%f", &alumno[i].cal[j]);
    if(alumno[i].cal[j] >= 6)
        printf("Pasa\n");
    else
        printf("No pasa\n");
}
```

Date cuenta que no hace falta el segundo `if`, es redundante.

**3.-** Sí vas a pedir una cadena por medio de `scanf`, evita el desbordamiento de búfer:

```c
//Con esto el usuario solo podrá ingresar 49 caracteres.
scanf("%49s", alumno[i].alum);
```

En este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383852/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-un-desbordamiento-de-b%C3%BAfer-cuando-se-pide-una-cadena-con-scanf) explico más a fondo sobre como evitar este tipo de desbordamiento.

El código corregido quedaría así:

```c
struct alumnos 
{
    char alum[50];
    float cal[10];
}alumno[10];

int i;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    printf("Ingresa el nombre de 10 alumnos junto con su calificacion de la materia de matematicas\n");
    
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("Nombre del alumno: \n");
        scanf("%49s", alumno[i].alum);      
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            printf("Ingrese la %d calificacion: \n", j + 1);
            scanf("%f", &alumno[i].cal[j]);
            if(alumno[i].cal[j] >= 6)
                printf("Pasa\n");
            else
                printf("No pasa\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Observación:**

No uses variables globales, no la necesitas en este caso. Mira este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales) para más información.

Comment: Ahora que ya se puede sacar quien paso y quien con, necesito saber como sacar el porcentaje de los que pasaron y los que no pasaron e imprimirlo en pantalla. Ya lo intente de varias maneras pero de ninguna me resulta. ¿Cómo puedo sacar el porcentaje de los que pasaron y los que no? Ayuda por favor

Comment: @Zamx Debes tener dos contadores (variables) que cuenten los que pasaron y los que no. Al final, para sacar el porcentaje, debes multiplicarlo por 100..

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estas aprendiendo y por eso cometes tantos errores de sintaxis. Asi que voy a expicar un poco cada cosa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Alumno {
    int calificacion;
    char nombre[20];
};


int main() {
    struct Alumno grupo[10];
    printf("Programa de ingreso de notas:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Ingrese nombre:");
        scanf("%s", &(grupo[i].nombre));
        printf("Ingrese nota:");
        scanf("%i", &(grupo[i].calificacion));
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Nombre: %s\n", grupo[i].nombre);
        printf("Calificacion: %i\n", grupo[i].calificacion);
        if (grupo[i].calificacion >= 6) printf("Estado: Aprobo.\n");
        else printf("Estado: No aprobo.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Como puedes notar, hay muchas diferencias con tu codigo.
Primero el uso de `scanf()` tiene 02 parametros, el primero es el tipo de dato que vas a insertar

- `%s` si es cadena de caracteres
- `%c` si es un solo caracter
- `%d` si es cualquier digito

Luego de esto es **obligatorio** usar el simbolo `&` antes de la variable.
Ej. `scanf("%s", &nombre);`
Segundo el uso de las variables de `struct`

Cuando usas un `struct` estas definiendo una clase(una clase es un tipo de variable inventado por ti) y llamas sus atributos(o elementos internos) con el `.`, en este caso he hecho un arreglo de 10 alumnos y a cada uno de ellos les he hecho insertar su nombre y su calificacion.
Luego al momento de imprimir los datos, ya teniendo todo ingresado, comparo la calificacion para ver si aprobo o no.

Por ultimo, al momento de operar arreglo o listas, debes usar los corchetes para indicar a que parte del arreglo vas a modificar.
Ej. `grupo[1].nombre;` te refieres al nombre del elemento 1 en el grupo.
Espero que todo esto te haya servido.