# Problemas con cadena de caracteres y punteros en C

Tags: c, punteros

Hola gente soy nuevo y espero que estén bien.
Estoy haciendo un programa en C con la intención de ingresar una cadena de caracteres y que me imprima la cantidad de caracteres que ingrese y es básicamente esto:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char c;
    char* ptr;
    ptr=&c;

    printf("Ingrese una secuencia de caracteres: ");
    scanf("%s",ptr);

    for(i=0;*(ptr+i)!='\0';i++)
    {

    }

    printf("\nEl conteo es de %d\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Ósea, estoy experimentando con punteros. Se que se debería declarar `char c[50]` por ejemplo pero quería ver que pasaba. No sé que tan mal este el programa ni cuál sea el error, pero cuando arranco el programa me sale 0, 2, 6 o **segmentatation fault** alguien me ayuda a entender? Muchas gracias.

Comment: en primer lugar `scanf` leerá la entrada hasta que haya un espacio. Luego hay que recordar que en C no existen los string, sino los arrays de caracteres.

Comment: Hola @Christian, espero que estés bien. 
Ajá. Entonces no vasta con tener una dirección de memoria, sino que para lo que quiero hacer tengo que si o si declarar un arreglo?

Comment: `char c` es un único caracter, por ejemplo `a`, si tu tienes `char cadena[50]` esto ya es un array donde vas a poder almacenar hasta 49 caracteres.

Comment: también lo probé con `char c[]={'c'};`, hace lo que quiero me pero al final me sale "stack samshing detected", que sucedió ahí? me arranco el programa igual y el compilador no detecto error aparente.

Comment: no haz declarado e tamaño del array, sería `char c[1] = {'c'}`, también pudes hacer `char c[] = "c"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Se que se debería declarar `char c[50]` por ejemplo pero quería ver que pasaba.

> No sé que tan mal este el programa ni cuál sea el error

No sientes que ambas oraciones se contradicen?

#### Porque hace eso?

Simulemos tu programa, y vamos a ver el stack y lo que pasa instruccion
a instruccion. En mi caso siempre me decia que el largo era 2, asi que eso es
lo que vamos a reproducir aqui:

De tus variables:

```cpp
    int i;
    char c;
    char* ptr;
```

Tendremos un stack que se vera algo como<sup>1</sup>:

```
Direccion | Valores
0x1       | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // char* ptr;
0x9       | 0x0 | // char c;
0xA       | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // int i;
```

Luego va esta linea:

```cpp
    ptr=&c;
```

Asi que le damos a `ptr` la direccion de `c`.

```
Direccion | Valores
0x1       | 0x9 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // char* ptr;
0x9       | 0x0 | // char c;
0x10      | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // int i;
```

Y luego lees:

```cpp
    scanf("%s",ptr);
```

Supongamos que el usuario ingresa 'Hola'. Como crees que se vera el stack?
Intenta hacerlo tu antes de continuar.

Lee primero la `H`:

```
Direccion | Valores
0x1       | 0x9 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // char* ptr;
0x9       | 0x48 (H) | // char c;
0x10      | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // int i;
```

Y si te das cuenta ya te terminaste la memoria que asignaste para la palabra,
pero `scanf` no sabe eso, asi que no se detendra, seguira escribiendo en las
siguientes direcciones de memoria. Tu stack puede parar algo similar a esto:

```
Direccion | Valores
0x1       | 0x9 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // char* ptr;
0x9       | 0x48 (H) | // char c;
0xA       | 0x6f (o) | 0x6c (l) | 0x61 (a) | 0x0 (\0) | // int i;
```

Ya aqui ya estamos muy mal, has sobreescrito `i`.

Ahora vamos a tu `for`, primero que nada, a `i` le damos el valor de `0`.

```
Direccion | Valores
0x1       | 0x9 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // char* ptr;
0x9       | 0x48 (H) | // char c;
0xA       | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // int i;
```

Lees en `(ptr+i)` (en la direccion `0x9`), que seria la `H`, y como no es igual
a `\0` incrementamos `i` en 1.

```
Direccion | Valores
0x1       | 0x9 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // char* ptr;
0x9       | 0x48 (H) | // char c;
0xA       | 0x1 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // int i;
```

Ahora cuando lees en `(ptr+i)` (en la direccion `0xA`), y como no es igual
a `\0` incrementamos `i` en 1. Ahora el stack es:

```
Direccion | Valores
0x1       | 0x9 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // char* ptr;
0x9       | 0x48 (H) | // char c;
0xA       | 0x2 | 0x0 | 0x0 | 0x0 | // int i;
```

Finalmente lee en `0xB`, y como esa direccion tiene el valor de `0x0` (el `\0`), ya termina el loop, dandole a `i` el valor final de `2`.

#### Comportamiendo indefinido

El leer o escribir en memoria que tu no has asignado es comportamiendo
indefinido, eso significa que no se puede asegurar que es lo que sucedera en
cada caso.

El error en este caso es tratar de escribir multiples caracteres en un buffer
que solo puede recibir uno, tienes un buffer overflow.

---

**1:** Dejare cada variable en una linea por claridad. Nota que lo mas probable
no es que esten inicializadas a 0, sino que tengan valores basura.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me ayudo mucho tu explicación a entender que pasaba en la memoria, justo eso quería saber. Sí, tiene razón, se contradicen, me expresé mal. Si la dirección de memoria al que apunta `ptr` esta muy "lejos" de donde se almacena `i`, entonces el programa seguiría sobrescribiéndose y dando un valor que en teoría es el deseado pero en la practica esta mal verdad? Lo digo porque puse  `char c[]={'c'};` a ver que onda y no detecto error el compi. Sale un valor, aunque la `ñ' lo cuenta como 2 y al final sale "stack samshing detected".

Comment: @El_Gordo_Freeman Si, tecnicamente ***podria*** funcionar, pero al ser comportamiento indefinido no se puede asegurar nada.

Comment: *ptr no deberia ocupar 4 bytes? Pregunto, no afirmo

Comment: Prueba con `std::cout << sizeof(char*) << '\n`. @HernánGarcia. Al final del dia dependera de tu arquitectura, en una maquina x64 tiene que ser de 8.

Comment: @Pablochaches. pues a mi me da 4 bytes. tengo windows x64. Soy muy novato en C (apenas pasé unas 5 horas sentado aprendiendo) pero sera debido a que el compilador MinGW que uso es 32 bits? Curioso, pero despues pones un int y lo muestras como de 4 bytes, no deberia ser tambien de 8 en x64? a mi me dan tanto int como char* 4 bytes con sizeof

Comment: Si, como MinGW es para 32 el puntero es de 4 bytes. *"no debería ser también de 8 en x64?"* No. El puntero tiene que ser de 8 para poder guardar todas las posibles direcciones de memoria en x64, pero bastan con 4 para todas las direcciones de x86, esa distinción no tiene nada que ver con el tamaño de `int`.

Comment: Entonces int es 4 bytes tanto rn x64 como en x86 cierto? El q si varia es el puntero

Comment: Supongo que si. @HernánGarcia

Answer (score 1):

los punteros en C, guardan la dirección de memoria dónde se encuentran los datos. En este caso, tu puntero apunta a un solo carácter, sin embargo, `scanf` tiene el `%s` que le indica es una cadena de caracteres Aquí ya tienes una inconsistencia. Pero en tu `for` haces la condición `ptr+i` aquí ya te saliste del límite al que apunta `ptr`. Para saber la cantidad de caracteres utiliza `strlen`

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char c[100];
    char* ptr;
    ptr=&c;

    printf("Ingrese una secuencia de caracteres: ");
    scanf("%s",ptr);

   

    printf("\nEl conteo es de %d\n",strlen(c));

    return 0;
}
```

Bueno ya sabes lo que pasa.

Answer (score 0):

> > No sé que tan mal este el programa ni cuál sea el error, pero cuando arranco el programa me sale 0, 2, 6 o segmentatation fault alguien me ayuda a entender?

Te pongo un ejemplo, ¿que hace este programa?

```c
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    char* ptr;
    ptr = &c;

    printf("Ingrese un caracter: ");
    scanf("%c", ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

El programa simplemente espera que el usuario ingrese únicamente un caracter (por algo usamos el especificador `%c`), luego `scanf` se encargará de almacenar ese caracter en la dirección (es decir, de la variable `c`) que apunte `ptr`.

Compara el ejemplo anterior con tu código actual... te darás cuenta que en la variable `c` solo podemos almacenar un valor. No deberíamos decirle lo contrario a `scanf`.

Si tu haces esto:

```c
printf("Ingrese un caracter: ");
scanf("%s", ptr);
```

Le estás indicando a `scanf` que lea un **conjunto de caracteres**, esto ocasiona un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) (significa que el comportamiento del programa puede ser cualquiera... puede que funcione o puede que no funcione).

Por ejemplo, aquí hay dos posibles comportamientos:

- `scanf` podría escribir en una dirección de memoria que esté usando el proceso actual (el programa ejecutándose), esto cambiaría por completo el comportamiento del programa.
- `scanf` podría intentar escribir en una dirección de memoria que **no fue** asignada al proceso actual (a esto denominamos [segmentatation fault](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso)), esto provoca que el sistema operativo mate al proceso actual, por lo que el programa abortaría.

### Observación

Por favor, nunca uses la función `scanf` de esa forma... podría ocasionar un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer). Siempre, siempre debes de especificar el tamaño del búfer en el primer parámetro de `scanf`. Para mas información, leer este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383852/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-un-desbordamiento-de-b%C3%BAfer-cuando-se-pide-una-cadena-con-scanf).