# Problema con scanf en C

Tags: c, xcode, scanf

Tenia que hacer una tarea en la cual el usuario pueda crear su propio usuario y una contraseña, primero empecé con la contraseña porque era difícil para mi, lo he hecho (la verdad no sé si está bien, pero funciona) éste es el programa final:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int password,password2;
int cont;   
char user;

int main (void)
{
    cont=3;
    printf(" \n                     Bienvenido a la Plataforma! \n");
    printf("Crea tu nombre de Usuario: ");
    scanf(" %c", &user);
    printf("Crea tu nueva contraseña: ");
    scanf("%d",&password);
    while (cont!=-1) {   
        printf("Escriba nuevamente su contraseña: ");   
        scanf("%d",&password2);
        if (password==password2){   
            printf("¡Tu contraseña a sido registrada!\n");  
            cont=0; 
        }
        else    
            if (cont==0){   
                printf("Has fallado 3 intentos, intente mas tarde\n");  
            }
            else{   
                printf("La contraseña es incorrecta. Tiene %d intentos \n", cont); 
                
            }
        cont--; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Pero luego quise integrar para que se pueda crear un usuario y ahí tengo el problema que al poner en marcha el programa, luego de escribir el usuario, se saltean lo de las contraseñas hasta que finaliza el programa, sin poder crear una contraseña y quedándome solo con el usuario, esto es lo que me dice al ejecutarlo:

```
 Bienvenido a la Plataforma! 
Crea tu nombre de Usuario: hola
Crea tu nueva contraseña: Escriba nuevamente su contraseña: ¡Tu contraseña a sido registrada!
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Porque me sucede esto? Como lo podria solucionar? :C

Comment: Tu `scanf` solo lee un caracter, en el ejemplo que colocaste leera la `h`, despues tratara de leer un entero, pero se topara con una `o`, al no ser un entero te retornara 0 indicando que no pudo leer nada y tu programa continuara. Pasara lo mismo con el otro. La solucion es leer un array de caracteres, no solo uno.

Comment: La contraseña debe guardarse en un array de caracteres, no en un entero. Si vas a pedir cadenas con scanf necesitas usar el especificador `%s` y no olvides de especificar el tamaño del búfer en el primer parámetro del [scanf](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383852/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-un-desbordamiento-de-b%c3%bafer-cuando-se-pide-una-cadena-con-scanf) para evitar desbordamiento de búfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas leyendo mal el nombre, como está solo puede leer un carácter. Debe ser algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int password,password2;
int cont;   
char user[40];

int main (void)
{
    cont=3;
    printf(" \n                     Bienvenido a la Plataforma! \n");
    printf("Crea tu nombre de Usuario: ");
    scanf("%s", user);
    printf("Crea tu nueva contraseña: ");
    scanf("%d", &password);
    while (cont!=-1) {   
        printf("Escriba nuevamente su contraseña: ");   
        scanf("%d",&password2);
        if (password==password2){   
            printf("¡Tu contraseña a sido registrada!\n");  
            cont=0; 
        }
        else    
            if (cont==0){   
                printf("Has fallado 3 intentos, intente mas tarde\n");  
            }
            else{   
                printf("La contraseña es incorrecta. Tiene %d intentos \n", cont); 
                
            }
        cont--; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores

1. Al declarar la variable user como char solo puedes guardar un caracter y tu quieres guardar una cadena de caracteres, prueba a cambiarlo por char[25] Asi podras guardar una cadena de 25 caracteres
2. Lo mismo con las contraseñas que las tienes declaradas como int, de esta manera solo puedes guardar numeros enteros, prueba a cambiarlo por char[25] también
3. Por último el scanf con %c solo guarda un caracter para guardar una cadena tienes que poner %s . No olvides cambiar tambien los %d al leer las contraseñas para que lean cadenas tambien

Comment: sabes que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/478294/edit) tu respuesta en lugar de eliminar y publicar una nueva? Tu primera respuesta estaba bastante bien

Answer (score 1):

Ok, la respuesta corta es **deja de usar `scanf()`**. Lo se, te ensenan a usar `scanf()` pero no te dicen los problemas que contrae usarle ni como resolververlos ni sus alternativas.

Pero vamos por parte:

1. `printf(" \n                     Bienvenido a la Plataforma! \n");` cambialo por `printf("\n\t\t\tBienvenido a la Plataforma! \n");`
2. Usando `fgets()` facilmente evitas este tipo de error `scanf(" %c", &user);`, estas diciendole a `scanf()` que recibira un `char` no un `string`. Deberia ser (con `fgets()`) `fgets(user, sizeof(user), stdin);` Ojo que `fgets()` no leera mas que `sizeof(user)` (el tamano en bytes de user) y eso es bastante bueno.
3. `char` solamente es para almacenar un character. Si quieres hacer una cadena debes usar **literal strings** o `char[]`. Recordande que el primero es inmutable (se guarda en la memoria de solo lectura) mientras que el otro se puede modificar.
4. Podemos usar `fgets()` con `sscanf()` para llevar the string a numeros. Seria:

   fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
   sscanf(line, "%d", &password);

### Todo en uno (con mas mejoras)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[100]; /* Temp var para guardar los inputs. */
    int password, password2;
    int cont;
    char user[100];
    cont = 3;

    printf("\n\t\t\tBienvenido a la Plataforma!\n");

    printf("Crea tu nombre de Usuario: ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(user), stdin); /* Guarda el input del userio a line. */
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; /* Cambia `\n` por `\0`. */
    strncpy(user, line, sizeof(user)); /* Copia lo que hay en line a user. */

    printf("Crea tu nueva contraseña: ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    sscanf(line, "%d", &password); /* Convierte lo que hay en line a numeros. */

    while (cont --> 0) /* Mientras cont sea mayor a 0, restale uno. Se conoce como */
                       /* goes to (la flecha). */
    {
        printf("Escriba nuevamente su contraseña: ");
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        sscanf(line, "%d", &password2);

        if (password == password2)
        {
            printf("¡Tu contraseña a sido registrada!\n");
            break;
        }

        if (cont == 0)
            printf("Has fallado 3 intentos, intente mas tarde\n");
        else
            printf("La contraseña es incorrecta. Tiene %d intentos \n", cont);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Resultado. #1

```
                        Bienvenido a la Plataforma!
Crea tu nombre de Usuario: djose1164
Crea tu nueva contraseña: 1234
Escriba nuevamente su contraseña: 1234
¡Tu contraseña a sido registrada!
```

### #2

```
                        Bienvenido a la Plataforma!
Crea tu nombre de Usuario: djose1164
Crea tu nueva contraseña: 123
Escriba nuevamente su contraseña: 1234
La contraseña es incorrecta. Tiene 2 intentos 
Escriba nuevamente su contraseña: 258
La contraseña es incorrecta. Tiene 1 intentos 
Escriba nuevamente su contraseña: 951
Has fallado 3 intentos, intente mas tarde
```

Sin mas que decir, espero haberte ayudado :D!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo, ahora entiendo mucho mejor ademas de aprender algo nuevo :D