# Arreglo básico en C, se hace infinito

Tags: array, c

Creo un arreglo con limite de 5, se supone que solo podría ingresar 4 caracteres, pero me permite ingresar una cantidad infinita de ellos, por que pasa esto?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char nombre[5];

    printf("Dame tu nombre: ");

    scanf("%s",nombre);

    printf("tu nombre es: %s",nombre);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo evitar un desbordamiento de búfer cuando se pide una cadena con scanf?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383852/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-un-desbordamiento-de-b%c3%bafer-cuando-se-pide-una-cadena-con-scanf)

Answer (score 4):

> se supone que solo podría ingresar 4 caracteres

Técnicamente no es así.

Si creas un array de 5 elementos, podrás almacenar en dicho array un máximo de 5 elementos.

Recordemos que un array no es más que un bloque de memoria. En este caso el bloque tiene 5 bytes:

```
 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 ...
| -- nombre -- | -- otras varaibles --
```

> pero me permite ingresar una cantidad infinita de ellos, por que pasa esto?

Esto pasa por dos razones:

1. Nadie va a comprobar si se superan los límites de un array. El único que en este caso podría hacer algo al respecto es el Sistema Operativo y solo va a actuar cuando escribas fuera de la memoria asociada a tu proceso. En ese caso actuará matando tu aplicación para que no corrompas memoria de otros procesos
2. `scanf` no conoce (tampoco es que le importe mucho) el tamaño de tu array. Tu le estás diciendo que quieres leer una cadena de caracteres, luego la función hará exactamente eso: Leer caracteres hasta que se encuentre un separador (espacio, tabulador, salto de línea). Que luego haya o no espacio para almacenar esa cadena ya es cosa tuya. Es por eso que `scanf` se considera una función insegura y se recomienda, por tanto, el uso de `scanf_s`

Lo que acaba sucediendo en tu programa es que `scanf`, al leer una cadena de más de 4 caracteres, empieza a escribir en posiciones de memoria que pertenecen a tu programa pero no a tu array, es decir, posiciones de memoria donde podrían encontrarse otras variables. Esto generalmente acaba provocando que tu aplicación se comporte de forma errática.

La mejor solución sería usar `scanf_s`. Esta es, digamos, la versión segura de `scanf`. Su uso no es muy diferente del que tiene actualmente `scanf`:

```
scanf_s("%s", nombre, sizeof(nombre));
```

Este mecanismo impide que se escriba fuera de los límites de tu array.

Otra solución sería, como te comentan en la otra respuesta, limitar la longitud de la cadena a leer. Lo que sucede en este caso es que tienes que acordarte de restar uno a la longitud del array:

```
scanf("%4s", nombre);
```